# Htaccess redirect rule not working without trailing slashes

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site I'm working on to change the domain over to a new one and we're currently having issues with this rewrite rule.

Examples of what's happening currently:

example.com/services to example.com/live/services/

example.com/services/ (not redirected)

example.com/ (not redirected)

The index.html files etc. are currently in a sub folder of /live/ and the rewrite rule should be serving the content from /live/ but when a trailing slash is not entered at the end of the URL it redirects to /live/xxx rather than serving the content.

This is the rule which I believe is causing the problems:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/live%{REQUEST_URI}" -f [OR]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/live%{REQUEST_URI}" -d
RewriteRule "^(.+)" "/live/$1"  [L]
```

Comment: That’s probably the effect of mod_dir, which issues a redirect if a folder was accessed without a trailing slash. You could disable `DirectorySlash` - but check the warnings in the documentation, before you do. It might make more sense here, that you make the slash optional at the end of your pattern, and then add one to the substitution.

Comment: @CBroe

I just tried that but it just showed the directory index page when accessed unfortunately.